# A topological space such that every subspace from it is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $\tau$ be the topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose open sets are of the form
>   $$G_t = \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>y+t\}, \; t\in \mathbb{R}$$
>   Is the union of two lines $r\cup s$ connected in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$?

What I did was consider $r\cup s$ as subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and assume that therexist $A$ and $B$ such that 
$$r\cup s = A\cup B$$
and $A\cap B =\emptyset$.
Then we can write $A$ and $B$ as
$$A=(r\cup s)\cap G_{t_1},\, B= (r\cup s)\cap G_{t_2}$$
But since for every $t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, $G_{t_1}\subset G_{t_2}$ or $G_{t_2}\subset G_{t_1}$, we have that
$$A\subset B\; \text{or}\; B\subset A$$
In any case, $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ and hence there is no separation of $r\cup s$, so $r\cup s$ is connected.

My question then is if this proof is okay, and also if it works too for any subspace of $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$ since I haven't use at all anything about the two lines. Also

> Are there other examples of topologies in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all subspaces are connected?

Comment: The proof is okay, and it works in every space in which the open sets are nested. That’s a hereditary property, so it works for all subspaces of such spaces as well.

Comment: There is a  flaw :  We can write $A=(r\cup s)\cap G_{t1}\lor A=(r\cup s)\cap \mathbb R^2$ and similarly for $B$.  But the conclusion $A\subset B\lor B\subset A$ will still hold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spaces which have every subspace connected are essentially the [*total preorders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders) EDIT: but see below.

In one direction, given a space $X$, define a relation $\le$ on $X$ given by $a\le b$ if every open set containing $b$, also contains $a$. This relation is clearly a preorder. If every subspace of $X$ is connected, then $\le$ is total: for every $a, b\in X$, either $a\le b$ or $b\le a$ (otherwise, $\{a, b\}$ would be a disconnected subspace of $X$).

Conversely, suppose $(L, \le)$ is a total preorder. Then we can turn $L$ into a topological space by taking as the opens those sets of the form $\{b: b\le a\}$ for $a\in L$. The preorder associated to this space is exactly $(L, \le)$. So this is an exact characterization.

---

This answer is actually incorrect in a subtle way, as Eric Wofsey points out below: the preorder assigned to a space does *not* characterize it! Specifically, we can have two spaces with isomorphic preorders, which are not homeomorphic. An easy example is: any two Hausdorff spaces with the same cardinality.

We can even come up with a hereditarily connected example! Let $X=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, and consider the following two topologies on $X$:

- $\tau=\{\{k, k+1, k+2, . . . \}\cup\{\infty\}: k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$,
- $\sigma=\{\{k, k+1, k+2, . . . \}\cup\{\infty\}: k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\{\infty\}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$.

It's easy to show that $\tau$ and $\sigma$ yield the same preorder.

However, this is a homeomorphism invariant for **finite** hereditarily connected spaces, or - even better - spaces whose associated preorder has finitely many equivalence classes. Roughly speaking, two hereditarily connected spaces with the same preorder differ only at the limit points in that preorder (although it's a bit messy to make this precise).

Comment: Fine, but it might be better to describe them as the spaces whose every *nonempty* subspace is connected.

Comment: @bof The empty space is connected, so I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: Depends on how you define connected. For some authors a space is connected if it has *exactly* one component.

Comment: @bof Isn't the emptyset its own unique connected component? It's a maximal subset which is connected in the seemingly-weaker sense. EDIT: Huh, nevermind, it's not a universal convention (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503442/empty-space-connected-if-so-then-what-are-its-components). Now I know!

Comment: I used to think "the empty space is connected" was a universal convention, until recently when I learned better by reading some answer on his site, maybe the one you linked to.

Comment: You haven't shown both directions here.  You've shown that if $X$ is hereditarily connected then its specialization preorder is total, and that every total preorder can come from a space, but multiple spaces can have the same preorder.

Comment: @EricWofsey DERP. This is not my day - fixed . . .

Answer (score 7):

Noah's answer is not quite correct (edit: he has now edited it to comment on this).  Given a topological space $X$, there is a preorder on $X$ defined by $a\leq b$ iff $b\in\overline{\{a\}}$, or equivalently if every open set containing $b$ contains $a$.  This is called the [specialization preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialization_(pre)order).  (There is no universal convention for which direction the order goes, so you will also see people define the specialization preorder as the opposite of how I have just defined it.)

As Noah showed, if every (nonempty) subset of $X$ is connected, then the specialization preorder must be total: if $a$ and $b$ are incomparable in the specialization preorder, then the subspace $\{a,b\}$ is disconnected.  Conversely, if the specialization preorder of $X$ is total, then every (nonempty) subset of $X$ is connected: every two-point subset is connected, which means any two points are in the same connected component of any subspace that contains both of them.

So every (nonempty) subset of $X$ is connected iff the specialization preorder is total.  And there are plenty of examples of topologies with total specialization preorder.  Indeed, any preorder at all can be the specialization preorder of a topology: given a preorder $\leq$ on $X$, take the topology generated by the sets $\{y\in X:y\leq x\}$ for each $x\in X$.

However, it is not accurate to say that such topologies on a set $X$ are "the same" as total preorders on $X$, since different topologies can give the same preorder.  For instance, let $X=\mathbb{R}$; then here are two different topologies whose specialization preorder is the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$.  The first topology is generated by the sets $(-\infty,x]$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  The second topology is generated by the sets $(-\infty,x)$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

The indiscrete topology $\{\mathbb R ^2,\varnothing\}$ also works.  Or for a $T_1$ example, let $X:=\{\langle n,0\rangle:n\in\omega\}$ and take a basis of sets $U\subseteq \mathbb R ^2$ such that $U=V\cup (X\setminus F)$ for some open $V$ in $\mathbb R ^2$ and $F\subseteq X$ finite. You cannot get better than $T_1$ (if the space is Hausdorff, then any set of size $2$ is not connected).

By the way, the beginning space $\mathbb R ^2$ does not matter for these examples.