# Compact iff connected

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X $ be a topological space in which any compact subset is connected and any connected space is compact.

I'm wondering the topological properties of such spaces. For example $X$ is not Hausdorff since all doubleton subsets $\{x,y\}$ for $x\ne y$ is compact, hence connected.

Thanks a million.

Comment: The finite complement topology doesn't have that property (unless the space consists of at most one point), the subspace topology on finite subspaces is discrete then, so finite subspaces with more than one point aren't connected. But they are of course (quasi)compact.

Comment: $X$ is connected and compact is an easy consequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank for comment.

Comment: @menag Note the question. Any compact is also connected and vise versa. But not any subset is compact (connected).

Comment: But there is just one connected component

Comment: Fix $x_0 \in X$ your favorite point and note that $X = \bigcup_{y \in X} \{x_0,y\}$ is the union of connected subsets, so that $\bigcap_{y \in X} \{x_0,y\} = \{x_0\}\neq \varnothing$ gives $X$ connected.

Comment: @menag May explain please, why we have just one component. Maybe you type an answer.

Comment: @IvoTerek Awesome! Thus $X$ is compact too. Is there any seperation axiom satisfies?

Comment: Unless $X$ consists of at most one point. If $X$ contains more than one point, it must be extremely non-$T_1$.

Comment: @Ivo Terek thanks

Comment: What about sequentially compactness or other type of connectedness? What about convergence of sequences, first or second countable?

Comment: The indiscrete topology on a set $X$ obeys this (so the class is not empty): every subset of $X$ is connected *and* compact

Comment: By the standard 5 spaces theorem, if $X$ is infinite, $X$ has an infinite indiscrete  subspace. I believe such a space can only have finitely many open sets maybe, no 2 of which can be disjoint. SO close to being indiscrete. For finite spaces we all subsets are compact so connected, which implies a lot of stuff on the specialisation pre-order.

Comment: Closely related (dealing with the connectedness part but not the compactness part): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890361/a-topological-space-such-that-every-subspace-from-it-is-connected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[In this answer I assume we are defining the empty set to be connected, or else requiring only that nonempty subsets be connected.]

> Let $X$ be a topological space.  Define a relation $\leq$ on $X$ by $x\leq y$ iff $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$ (this is the [specialization preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialization_(pre)order), or maybe its opposite depending on your conventions).  It is easy to see that $\leq$ is transitive.  Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. A subspace of $X$ is compact iff it is connected
> 2. Every subspace of $X$ is both compact and connected
> 3. The relation $\leq$ is a pre-well ordering: that is, it is total and every nonempty subset of $X$ has a least element.

To prove this we will prove $(2)\Rightarrow (1)\Rightarrow (3)\Rightarrow (2)$. The implication $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$ is trivial.

Let us now suppose $(1)$ holds and prove that $(3)$ holds (we will also prove that $(2)$ holds along the way).

To prove totality of $\leq$, note that for any $x,y\in X$, $\{x,y\}$ is compact and hence connected.  If $x\not\leq y$, then $\{y\}$ is closed as a subset of $\{x,y\}$, so $\{x\}$ cannot be closed by connectedness.  This means that $y\in\overline{\{x\}}$, so $y\leq x$.  Thus either $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$.

It follows also that actually every subset of $X$ is connected.  Indeed, if $A\subseteq X$ and $x,y\in A$, then since $\{x,y\}$ is connected a clopen subset of $A$ contains $x$ iff it contains $y$.  It follows that a clopen subset of $A$ either contains no elements of $A$ or contains all elements of $A$, so $A$ is connected.

Thus every subset of $X$ is also compact.  We now use this to prove that any nonempty subset $A\subseteq X$ has a least element.  First, note that for any $x\in X$, the set $U(x)=\{y\in X:y\not\leq x\}$ is open in $X$.  Indeed, if $y\in U(x)$, then since $y\not\leq x$ there exists some open set $U$ such that $y\in U$ but $x\not\in U$.  For any $z\in U$, then, $x\not\leq z$ since $U$ is a neighborhood of $z$ not containing $x$.  Thus $U\subseteq U(x)$.

Note also that if $y\leq x$, then $U(x)\subseteq U(y)$.

Now suppose there exists a nonempty subset $A\subseteq X$ which has no least element.  For each $a\in A$, there exists some $b\in A$ such that $a\not\leq b$, so that $a\in U(b)$.  So $A$ is covered by the open sets $U(b)$.  Since $A$ is compact, there are finitely many $b_1,\dots,b_n\in A$ such that the sets $U(b_i)$ cover $A$.  Taking a least element among the finitely many $b_i$ (which is possible since $\leq$ is total), we see there is a single element $b\in A$ such that $U(b)$ covers $A$.  But this is impossible, since $b\in A$ and $b\not\in U(b)$.

Thus every nonempty subset of $X$ has a least element, so $\leq$ is a pre-well ordering of $X$.  This concludes the proof that $(1)\Rightarrow (3)$.

Now suppose $(3)$ holds; we will prove $(2)$.  The argument with two-point subspaces above can easily be reversed to show that if $\leq$ is total, then every two-point subspace of $X$ is connected, and that this implies in fact every subspace of $X$ is connected.  So it just remains to be shown that every subspace of $X$ is compact.

To prove this, let $A\subseteq X$ be any nonempty subspace.  By assumption, there is a least element $a\in A$.  For any $b\in A$, then, $a\in\overline{\{b\}}$, which means any open set containing $a$ contains $b$.  So the only open subset of $A$ containing $a$ is the entire space $A$.  It follows that any open cover of $A$ must have $A$ itself as one of the open sets, so there is trivially a finite subcover (namely $\{A\}$).  Thus every subspace of $X$ is compact.

Comment: It is standard usage that the empty space is connected: The standard def'n is that $X$ is connected iff whenever $A, B$ are open with $A\cup B=X$ and $A\cap B=\phi$ then $(A=X \lor B=X).$ Or (equivalently) that $X$ is not the union of a pair of dsjoint  non-empty open sets . Or (equivalently), that a subset of $X$ that is open and closed is empty or is $X.$ ............ Good answer.