# Find an example of a topological space with a topology different from the indiscrete topology in which every subset is connected

Tags: general-topology

Find an example of a topological space with a topology different from the indiscrete topology in which every subset is connected.

I can only think of a space with one single point, but then every topology will be the indiscrete topology.

Comment: For a general characterization of these spaces, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890361/a-topological-space-such-that-every-subspace-from-it-is-connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A = \{ a,b \}$ with topology $\tau = \{ \varnothing, \{a\}, A \}$, then it is not the indiscrete topology.
Isn't this one connected?

---

**Edit:**
This is the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).
And it is indeed [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space#Connectedness).

Comment: Thank you. I'm having trouble with all the equivalent definitions of a disconnected set.

Comment: This little space is an example or counter-example for  many Q's in topology.

Answer (score 1):

I think $X = \mathbb{N}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset ,\mathbb{N}\} \cup \{L_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $L_n =\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the so-called lower topology.

The same set with the upper topology $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{U_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $U_n = \{k \in \mathbb{N}: k \ge n\}$ also has this property.

Comment: In a way, the Sierpinski space is a particular case of your first example: if we think of $\mathbb{N}$ in your example as an ordinal, and in the Sierpinski space it's the finite ordinal $2$. I suspect this can even be generalized for other ordinals. Certainly for finite ones, maybe for limit ordinals, at least.

Comment: I think Eric Wofsey's answer to the question in the link he gives in a comment to the question answers my suspicion in the positive.

Comment: @amrsa yes, the open sets being linearly ordered is crucial for these examples.