# Is there the empty topological space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

1. May the empty set be a topological space?
   Is the set $\{\emptyset\}$ its topology?
2. What about the empty metric space?

Comment: Does it satisfy the axioms of a topological space?

Comment: My professor defined a metric/topological space as a **nonempty** set equipped with ... .  I must therefore thank her for having  saved us from the present fruitless discussions!

Comment: @Black You have been made a considerable disservice, because you'll have to make caveats on the existence of coproducts of families of spaces, the existence of products will have to be unnaturally subordinated to the axiom of choice and Tychonov theorem will be way less elegant.

Comment: @Black Not including the empty topological space means that its not a complete or cocomplete category. We need the empty topological space, it's very important.

Answer (score 5):

1. Definitely yes and yes. In point of fact, it's the initial object of the category of topological spaces. It is compact, but as far as I know it is currently a matter of debate whether it should be considered connected or not.
2. I would say yes ([like wikipedia does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)). It's homeomorphic to the empty topological space and it still is the initial object in all the categories I can think of putting on metric spaces (namely: the category with continuous maps, or the category of uniformly continuous maps, or the category of Lipschitz maps, or the category of non-expansive maps).

Comment: Thank You!  What should we mean by distance in the empty metric space?

Comment: @NurlanAbiev It's just the empty function (the unique function $\emptyset \times\emptyset\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, defined by "").

Comment: Every continuous function $\emptyset\to\{0,1\}$ is constant. A space $X$ is disconnected if and only if there are nonempty open sets $A,B$ such that $A\cup B=X$; the empty space doesn't satisfy this property. These seem strong enough reasons to declare that the empty space is connected.

Comment: @egreg I think [there is no standard convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503442/empty-space-connected-if-so-then-what-are-its-components/503446) about whether the empty space is connected.

Comment: @egreg Some people have [arguments for the contrary](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+space). I'm not a mathematician, so I don't quite manipulate the theory at a level where I can see the difference.