# An arbitrary product of connected spaces is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, product-space

> Let $\lbrace X_\alpha \rbrace_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of connected spaces; let $X$ be the product space $$X=\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$$
>
> Let **a**$=(a_\alpha)$ be a fixed point of $X$.
>
> Given any finite subset $K$ of $J$, let $X_K$ denote the subspace of $X$ consisting of all points **x**$=(x_\alpha)$ such that $x_\alpha=a_\alpha$ for $\alpha \notin K$. Show that $X_K$ is connected.

As the title suggests, this is part 1 of 3 to show that $X$ is connected (found in Munkres' Topology, second edition, p. 152). The other parts look fairly straightforward, but this one has been a little tricky for me; the main problem is that $J$ might be uncountable, which makes traditional index notation unusable.

My approach so far has been to show that $X_K$ is homeomorphic to a finite sub-product of $X$. If $|K|=n$ (which is known to be finite), then let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be the $n$ indices for which **x** and **a** differ. Also let $$Z=\prod_{m=\alpha_1}^{\alpha_n} X_m$$

I suspect that $X_K$ is homeomorphic to $Z$. The most natural map would be $f: X_K \rightarrow Z$ defined by, for **x** $\in X_K$, "stripping off" all coordinates of **x** which disagree with **a**, leaving only finitely many. The inverse would take **z** $\in Z$ and "fill in" the coordinates of **a** that are missing.

I haven't tried showing that $f$ is invertible or continuous for uncountable $J$, but I have tried for countable indices; invertibility doesn't seem to be a problem, but continuity is tripping me up:

> When $J$ is countable, without loss of generality, take $J=\mathbb{N}$ and $K=\lbrace 1,2,...,n \rbrace$, so $$Z=\prod_{m=1}^n X_m $$Now **a**=$(a_1,a_2,...)$, and **x** $\in X_K$ has the form $(x_1,...,x_n,a_{n+1},...)$. Thus $f(x_1,...,x_n,a_{n+1},...)=(x_1,...,x_n)$.
>
> Suppose $U$ is open in $Z$. Then $U=U_1 \times ... \times U_n$, where $U_i$ is open in $X_i$. $f^{-1}(U)=U_1 \times ... \times U_n \times \lbrace a_{n+1} \rbrace \times...$.

It seems difficult to conclude that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, as the singleton sets appended on the end may or may not be open in their individual sets, depending on the properties of the $X_i$. The approach also seems awkward when attempting to generalize to uncountable indices.

Apologies for the long question statement, but one more request - please **NO FULL SOLUTIONS**. I am working through this for an assignment and would like to figure it out on my own, even though I am momentarily stumped.

Comment: hint: $X_{K}$ is a SUBspace of $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you don't need to show $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, only that it is open in the subspace $X_K$ of $X$.  I would also remark that the uncountable case should be no harder than the countable case; it's just a matter of notation.  If $J$ is uncountable, you can still label the elements of $K$ with natural numbers $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$; the only difference is that the remaining elements of $K$ will not be other natural numbers (and you don't really care what they are).

Comment: When you say "the remaining elements of $K$ will not be other natural numbers", did you mean $J$ instead of $K$?

Comment: Oops, yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, only Hints:

1) countable or not? Doesn't care. The only thing that matters is that $K$ is finite

2) $f$ is not continue if you go from $X$ to $Z$, but your $f$ is from $X_K$ to $Z$, and $X_K$ has a different topology..