# Show that $X_K$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha} $ be a collection of connected spaces.Let $X$  be the product space $X=\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ .

Let **a**=$(a_\alpha)$ be a fixed point of $X$.

a.Given any finite subset $K$ of $J$ ,let $X_K$ denote the subspace of $X$ consisting of all points **x**=$x_\alpha$ such that $x_\alpha=a_\alpha$for $\alpha \notin K$.Show that $X_K$ is connected.

b.Show that $Y=\cup X_K$ is connected.

If I am able to show that $X_K$ is connected and $X_{K_i}\cap X_{K_j}\forall i\neq j$ then we are done.

But I am not getting how to solve (a). Please help.

Comment: $X_K$ is homeomorphic to a product of finitely many connected spaces. If you know that the product of two connected spaces is connected, then you can conclude that $X_K$ is connected.

Comment: Maybe this link is interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322057/an-arbitrary-product-of-connected-spaces-is-connected?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this problem, I tried to do it without using the homeomorphism, I'm not sure at all if the solution is rigorously correct (it seems to me, correct me otherwise):

I will use that $X_K$ is connected iff the only closed and open sets are $X_K$ and $\emptyset$ (in its relative topology)

\begin{equation}
\text{By definition: $X_K = \prod_\alpha A_\alpha$ such that}
\begin{cases}
A_\alpha = \{a_\alpha\} &\alpha \notin K \\
A_\alpha = X_\alpha &\alpha \in K \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Let $P \subseteq X_K$ an open and closed set, then $P = X_K \cap G$ with $G$ an open set of the product topology in $X$, and using that
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i\in I}M_i \cap \prod_{i\in I}N_i = \prod_{i\in I}M_i \cap N_i
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{$\Rightarrow P = \prod_\alpha B_\alpha$ such that}
\begin{cases}
B_\alpha = \{a_\alpha\} &\alpha \notin K \\
B_\alpha \subseteq X_\alpha \text{(an open set of $X_\alpha$)} &\alpha \in K \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then $X_K - P = \prod_\alpha C_\alpha$ which is open (because P is closed), and using that
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i\in I}M_i - \prod_{i\in I}N_i = \prod_{i\in I}M_i-N_i
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\prod_\alpha C_\alpha =
\begin{cases}
C_\alpha = \{a_\alpha\} &\alpha \notin K\\
C_\alpha = X_\alpha - B_\alpha \text{(an open set of $X_\alpha$)} &\alpha \in K\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

from here we get that $C_\alpha = X_\alpha - B_\alpha$ is an open and closed set in $X_\alpha \forall \alpha \in K$

Every $X_\alpha$ is connected, so we have 2 options for each $C_\alpha$: $C_\alpha = \emptyset$ or $C_\alpha = X_\alpha$

If there is at least one $\alpha \in K$ such that $C_\alpha = X_\alpha$, then $B_\alpha = \emptyset$ and we have that $P = \prod_\alpha B_\alpha = \emptyset$

If not, $C_\alpha = \emptyset, \forall \alpha \in K$, so $B_\alpha = X_\alpha, \forall \alpha \in K$, and then $P = \prod_\alpha B_\alpha = X_K$

That is to say that if P is an open and closed set, is either the empty set or $X_K$, so $X_K$ is connected.