# Product of connected sets is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I know that this question had already been asked here but there is a problem ... all the proofs that I've seen used homeomorphisms and continuous functions. Well my teacher didn't teach me what a homeomorphism is so I cannot use the concept.

The question is:

> Show that the product of connected sets $A$ in $X$ and $B$ in $Y$ is connected for the product topology.
>   Hints:
>   a) If $b$ belongs to $Y$, the product $A\times\{b\}$ is connected
>   b) Using a), the product $A\times B$ is connected

Well, my try:
I know that $A\times B$ is connected if the only partition of the set is the trivial.
But I don't know how to relate this with the hints ... Can somebody give me more hints, please?

Comment: I don't know the answer outright, but assume you do have a disconnection. Can you somehow prove that this induces a disconnection of $A$ or $B$?

Comment: You mean by mathmatical absurd? Because I think that it's not suppose to use that...i's suppose to prove with the hints given by the teacher

Comment: I think any way about this will at least smuggle in homeomorphisms by some sort of backdoor trick.

Comment: So I get the concept of continuous function has been introduced?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need the definition of homeomorphisms to prove the statement. I assume you know this fact 1: Let $S,T$, $S \subset T$ two subset of a topological space $X$, assume that $S$ is connected and $T$ is not connected. If $(U,V)$ is a separation of $T$ then $S \subset U$ or $S \in U$. Here is a proof of the following fact2: Let X and Y two topological spaces, then $X \times Y$ is connected $\Leftrightarrow X,Y$ are connected. $(\Leftarrow)$ suppose that $X,Y$ are connected and $(U,V)$ is a couple of open nonempty sets which unconnect $X \times Y$ which means $X \times Y= U \bigcup V$. Now let $(x_0,y_0) \in U$. The set ${x_0} \times Y$ is connected because it is homeomorphic to $Y$(it is very easy to show!). ${x_0}\times Y$ contains $(x_0,y_0)$ then for fact 1 ${x_0} \times Y \subset U$. On the other hand $\forall y \in Y$, the set $X \times y$ is connected because is homeomorphic to X and contains $(x_0,y) \in U$. Again for fact 1 we can deduct that $X \times y \subset U$. Then $X \times Y= \bigcup_{y \in Y} X \times y \subset U$ $\Rightarrow$ $X \times Y=U$ and $V$ is empty, which is absurd because we supposed that $V$ is nonempty. This contradiction shows that $X \times Y$ can't be unconnected then is connected. $(\Rightarrow)$ Assume that $X \times Y$ is connected, define the canonical projection $\pi: X \times Y \rightarrow X$, $\pi$ is surjective and a continuous map, and for the principal theorem of connection you easily conclude that $X$ is connected. The same reasoning shows that also $Y$ is connected. $\Box$
The principal theorem of connection says that if $X,Y$ are a topological spaces with X connected and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map, then $f(X)$ is connected.

Comment: But i cannot use homeomorphisms here

Comment: Then you can just prove that there is a bijection between those sets so you can identify one with the other

Comment: But there is another way to prove it without functions? (i am asking this because the next chapter that the teacher will teach us is homeomorphism and continuous functions, and I know that he doesnt want us to use functions here)

Comment: I don't think so. Using the Hints you wrote you should then relate the $x \times X$ to $X$ so I don't see any more other natural way than using functions

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'product of subspaces = subspace of products' (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1992964/432081)), the question boils down to showing that the product of two connected spaces is connected. The answer to that question, using the OP's hints, can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338051/432081).