# Subspace and Product topologies

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I wish to prove the following statement.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces with $A \subset X$ and $B\subset Y$.  Then prove that the topology on $A \times B$ as a subspace of the product $X\times Y$ is the same as the product topology on $A\times B$, where $A$ and $B$ have the subspace topology from $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Well I understand that the first thing looks like:

$$
\{(A\times B) \cap (U_i \times V_i)|U_i,V_i \in \text{topology on $X$ and $Y$ respectively}\}
$$

Isn't it a set theory law that this is 
$$
\{(A\cap U_i) \times (B \cap V_i)|U_i,V_i \in \text{topology on $X$ and $Y$ respectively}\}
$$
Then we are done.  Or do I have to use double containment?  Also, does anyone have a good list of the non-special case set distributive laws?

Thank you.

Comment: Your first expression seems to assume that the set $\{U_i \times V_i \,\bigm|\, U_i,V_i \in \text{topology on $X$ and $Y$ respectively}\}$ is the product topology on $X \times Y$, but that is false. That set is only a basis for the product topology.

Comment: Yes but I was meaning the { } to indicate a basis.does this not work?

Comment: Since you did not say that the $\{\}$ indicates a basis, and instead said that $\{\}$ indicates the topology, then no, it does not work. If you do decide to say that the $\{\}$ indicates a basis, then you will have to correctly apply theorems which relate bases and the topologies that they generate, because what you must prove is equality of the topologies.