# Connectedness in Product Topology via Simple Chain

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, product-space

It is well known that if $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be two connected topological spaces then $(X\times Y,\tau)$ is also connected where $\tau$ is the product topology on $X\times  Y$.

However, all the proofs that I have seen either uses an argument like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338056/170039) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338051/170039) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823911/170039).

But after seeing Theorem 26.15 from [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=simple+chain+and+connectedness&source=bl&ots=TTibGe-IKz&sig=noccxVm0UOVfN-IBFKfSTd78FOs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUxMjpxd_ZAhXF6Y8KHbplD3QQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=simple%20chain%20and%20connectedness&f=false) I was wondering whether it is possible to prove the following using the simple chain condition.

> **Definition of simple chain connecting two points.** A simple chain connecting two points $a$ and $b$ of a space $X$ is a sequence $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ of open sets such that $a\in U_1$ only and $b\in U_n$ only and $U_i\cap U_j\ne\emptyset$ iff $|i-j|\le 1$.

More specifically,

> 1. Let $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be two connected topological spaces. Show that $(X\times Y,\tau)$ is also connected by proving that given any two points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in X\times Y$ and any open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $X\times Y$ there exists a simple chain from $\mathscr{U}$ connecting $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.
> 2. Let $X_i$, $i \in I$ is a family of nonempty topological spaces, all of which are connected spaces. Show the product space $\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} X_i$, endowed with the product topology, is also connected by proving that given any two points ${\bf{x},\bf{y}}\in \displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ and any open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $\displaystyle\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ there exists a simple chain from $\mathscr{U}$ connecting $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work. It is *not* true that a topological space $X$ is connected if and only if, for any two points $x,y\in X$, there is a simple chain connecting them. Because for any two points $x,y\in X$ (whether $X$ is connected or not) you can always find such a chain: just take $n=1$ and $U_1=X$.

Comment: The definition states $x \in U_1$ *only* and $y \in U_n$ *only*. Presumably, this means $x \not \in U_i$ for $i \neq 1$, and similarly for $y$.

Comment: @lisyarus I don't understand your objection. It is obvious that $x\in U_1$ only and $y\in U_1$ only. There is no $U_i$ for $i>1$.

Comment: You are right. I mean, probably it is meant that $n \geq 2$? Still, your answer is correct.

Comment: Looking in the book, the theorem is actually that $X$ is connected if and only if, for any open cover $\mathscr{U}$, there is a simple chain connecting any two elements whose elements belong to $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: @AlexZorn Right! It is essential to add this part concerning the open covers.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how your post answers my questions. What am I missing?

Comment: @user170039 I proved thatt*every* topological space (connected or not) satisfies the condition that you mentioned. Therefore, the condition cannot be used to prove that a space is connected.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I have made a small edit to make my question more precise. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @user170039 THat is not a small edit; it's a huge one. Anyway, my answer applied to your question as it was stated at the time I've provided it.