# why $ \bigcup (X \cup Y)= X\times Y $?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, product-space

I have some confusion in Munkres topology . My confusion is given below  marked in red colour

[image]

**My attempt** :  Here ${\bigcup}_{x\in X} T_x = \bigcup(X \times b) \cup (x \times Y)= \bigcup (X \cup Y)$

**My doubt** :  why $ \bigcup (X \cup Y)= X\times Y $?

Comment: Essentially, the problem is that the line labelled as "**My attempt**" is nonsense.

Comment: In $\rm\LaTeX$ `\bigcup` gives you $\bigcup$ which is an operator on a family of sets; whereas $\cup$ is an operator on two sets; you wouldn't understand if I wrote $+n+k$ as $\sum n+k$, would you?

Comment: I will add a link to an older thread which contain several various proofs: [Product of connected spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338027).

Comment: oh sorry  @AsafKaragila next time i will be careful

Comment: There's an [edit] button, just so you know. Questions are not etched into marble here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let $(p,q) \in X \times Y$. Then $$(p,q) \in p \times Y \subseteq T_p \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in X} T_x$$ As all $T_x \subseteq X \times Y$ the other inclusion is trivial.

Comment: ..@Henno sir  i thinks it should be $(p,q) \in p \times Y$

Answer (score 3):

The expression  $ \cup (X \cup Y)$ does not make sense.

Obviously we have

$$ X \times Y = \bigcup_x \{x\} \times Y \subset \bigcup_x T_x \subset X \times Y .$$
This implies $\bigcup_x T_x = X \times Y$.

Comment: Actually, $\union X$ typically means the union of all sets contained in $X$

Comment: @Couchy See Asaf Karagila's comment to the question. The original version was $\cup (X \cup Y)$. But even in the version $\bigcup (X \cup Y)$ - what are sets contained in $X \cup Y$?